# Symfony2 - can't display values from an entity

Tags: symfony, doctrine

I'm finding (using `findOneBy`) a singe row in my entity. Here's the code:

```
$userown = $this->getDoctrine()->getRepository('GameShelfUsersBundle:Own')
    ->findOneBy(array(
        'game' => $game->getId(),
        'user' => $em->getRepository('GameShelfUsersBundle:User')->find($session->getId())
    ));
```

Now I pass it to template as `userown`. But when I try to print it in twig, using `{{ userown.typo }}`, it throws an error:

```
An exception has been thrown during the rendering of a template ("Catchable Fatal Error: Object of class Proxies\__CG__\GameShelf\UsersBundle\Entity\OwnState could not be converted to string in D:\!!XAMPP\htdocs\
```

My Entity is [here](http://pastebin.com/RraXX3jA).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Doctrine automatically resolves your foreign keys, so `$typo` is not a string but an object.  As the error message tells you, this object cannot be converted to a string, so printing it fails.

You can either implement the `__toString()` method inside your `OwnState` Entity (it should return a string) or you print an actual property of the OwnState object: `{{ userown.type.someProperty }}`.

Comment: Darn, it's so obvious, I just forgot about it ;) Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Are you sure this is correct

`'game' => $game->getId()`

I think it should be the game object itself rather than the id

`'game' => $game,`

Comment: Dude ... you really made my day !!!
instead use: $language = $em->getRepository('LanguageBundle:Language')->find($translation->getLanguage());, I just used: $language = $translation->getLanguage(); !!!!